# How to write -1 as a square in a finite field of characteristic 2

Tags: finite-fields, square-numbers

If $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ is a finite field of characteristic $2$, where $q$ is a power of $2$ and $\beta$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}^{*}$, then I know that $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}$, but how do I find $1\leq k \leq q-2$ such that $\beta^{k}=-1$?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is $q$? Is $\mathbb{F}=GF(2^q)?$

Comment: @gammatester I guess the field size? $q$ is some power of $2$.

Comment: -1 = 1 in such a field, right?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning; $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{F}_{q}$, where $q$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: Edited the mistake just now.

Comment: @Henno Yes, you are right! I completely forgot that. So there is no such $q$ since $\beta^{q-1}=1=-1$.

Comment: That's what I would say, yes.

Comment: What Henno said is, of course, correct, but I would still rather say that $\beta^0=1=-1$. No need to go to extremes and use $q-1$ as the exponent IMHO :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the characteristic is $2$ then $1=-1$. Being $\beta$ a generator of $\mathbb{F}^*$ the smallest $k$ such that $\beta ^k=-1=1$ is $q-1$. Then there's no such $k$ in $\{1,...,q-2 \}$.